# SQL get column value associated with max()

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
ID     Version         
---    ----------    
123      1           
124      2           
125      3           
126      4           
127      5           
128      6
```

Now I need to get ID value where version# is maximum

What I can do is

```
select ID from tbl where version = (select max(version) from tbl)
```

I don't want to use this since i need to use this part in a join inside another query and i don't want to complicate things further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use select [FIRST()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp):

```
SELECT FIRST(id) FROM tbl ORDER BY Version DESC
```

Or limit the number results using *LIMIT 1* option:

```
SELECT id FROM tbl ORDER BY Version DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Neither of those is standard SQL, and the OP didn't specify the database. (Edit: actually, I do not know for sure what is part of the SQL standard, but more relevant is that I do know that there are database engines widely used that do not support either of these.)

Comment: @hvd you are right but the OP should mention the DBMS is its relevant, guess he would have to once it doesnt work for him.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you need this in a join, so something like this should do it

```
select *
from table_1 as t1
  join (
      select id, 
             row_number() over (order by version desc) as rn
      from table_2
  ) as t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t2.rn = 1
```

(This is ANSI SQL as you didn't mention a DBMS - but should work on most modern DBMS)